# Execute a exe file with arguments using cmd in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a windows application.I am calling a command prompt,I need to call exe file that exe file take parameter.

I am able to open command prompt but not able to send the parametrs

```
        string  strCmdText = "create-keyfile.exe ..\\KatanaFirmware\\key-template.txt ..\\Keyfiles\\new-keyfile.txt " + cableTextBox.Text.Trim()+" " + startIdTextBox.Text.Trim();
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Can please help me out.

Thanks

Punith

Answer (score 5):

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("create-keyfile.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "..\\KatanaFirmware\\key-template.txt ..\\Keyfiles\\new-keyfile.txt " + cableTextBox.Text.Trim()+" " + startIdTextBox.Text.Trim();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

You can also see  [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) on Process.Start, there are examples on how to execute .exe and pass arguments to it.

Comment: if it solves your problem you should accept answer so others can see that question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.FileName = "yourprogram.exe";
process.Arguments = strCmdText; // or put your arguments here rather than the string
Process.Start(process);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe "+strCmdText);
```

Actually on further inspection I don't think you need to call CMD.EXE
You should be calling your exe file, unless of course you are using CMD to to display something

```
string  strCmdText =  "..\\KatanaFirmware\\key-template.txt ..\\Keyfiles\\new-keyfile.txt " + cableTextBox.Text.Trim()+" " + startIdTextBox.Text.Trim();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("create-keyfile.exe", strCmdText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cmd with [/k or /c option](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true)

From the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true)

/c : Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.

/k : Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

```
   string  strCmdText = "/k create-keyfile.exe ..\\KatanaFirmware\\key-template.txt ..\\Keyfiles\\new-keyfile.txt " + cableTextBox.Text.Trim()+" " + startIdTextBox.Text.Trim();
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
string  strCmdText = "KatanaFirmware\\key-template.txt "+ "\\Keyfiles\\new-keyfile.txt " + cableTextBox.Text.Trim()+" " +     startIdTextBox.Text.Trim();
Process mp = new Process();
mp.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\create-keyfile.exe"; //path of the exe that you want to run
mp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
mp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
mp.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdText;
mp.Start();
mp.WaitForExit();
```

Hope it helps.